# Change sail db configuration - failed: port is already allocated

Tags: laravel, docker

I'm trying to create a new laravel app using sail. However, with this command:

```
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

It shows:

```
Attaching to test-app-laravel.test-1, test-app-mysql-1
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint test-app-mysql-1 Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated
```

Im using docker and I have another app using that port. Do you know how to change the sail configuration to use a different one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the `docker-compose.yml` configuration, by default the `mysql` configuration should have a `${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306` on the ports entry. Add `FORWARD_DB_PORT=33060` (or other port) to your `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks but now it shows the same for the port 80 like: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated. I changed to another on the docker-compose.yml but it still shows this error. Do you know how solve that?

Comment: @Nelb What did you change on the `docker-compose.yml` file to update the app port? By default you add  `APP_PORT=8080` (or other empty port) to your `.env` file to change the laravel app port. You can read the environment variables, they're saved in a `${ENV_VARIABLE:-DEFAULT}` format.